# Parsing an EnumSet with Retrofit

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit to hit an api that will give me the state of the doors on a car. This is what the reply looks like:

```
{
    "response": {
        "driver_front": 0,
        "driver_rear": 0,
        "passenger_front": 0,
        "passenger_rear": 0,
        "trunk": 0,
    }
}
```

Ideally I want to parse it into an EnumSet like this:

```
public enum Doors
{
    DRIVER_FRONT,
    DRIVER_REAR,
    PASSENGER_FRONT,
    PASSENGER_REAR,
    TRUNK
}
private EnumSet<Doors> _openDoors = EnumSet.noneOf(Doors.class);
```

But I can't figure out how to get it into that format. I tried adding a boolean to the enum to show the state and add a custom deserializer but that never got called and even if it would have I'd only get the value, not the key so I wouldn't know which door it was for. Anyone have any neat tricks for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Serialized name in your enum because GSON provides default serialization and deserialization for Enums ([Official documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html))

```
public enum Doors {

    @SerializedName("0")
    DRIVER_FRONT (0), 

    @SerializedName("1")
    DRIVER_REAR (1),

    @SerializedName("2")
    PASSENGER_FRONT (2),

    @SerializedName("3")
    PASSENGER_FRONT (3),

    @SerializedName("4")
    TRUNK (4);

    private final int value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    private Doors(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm using that elsewhere but that's for the value coming from the json.

Comment: @CaseyB Wait looks like I misunderstand your question, will try to think a solution and update my answer later.